# Remove XML content on a given node and rearrange the output file format

Tags: java, xslt

[XSLT stylesheet]

In the example below,

```
<tag1>
    <tag2>
        ...
            <generatoritem id="name1">
                <tag5>
                ...
                    <tag6>
                        <name>Center</name>
                        <keyframe>
                            <when>frame1</when>
                            <value>
                                <horiz>100</horiz>
                                <vert>100</vert>
                            </value>
                        </keyframe>
                        <keyframe>
                            <when>frame2</when>
                            <value>
                                <horiz>150</horiz>
                                <vert>150</vert>
                            </value>
                        </keyframe>
                    </tag6>
                </tag5>
            </generatoritem>
            <generatoritem id="name2">
                <tag7>
                ...
                    <tag8>
                        <name>Center</name>
                        <keyframe>
                            <when>frame3</when>
                            <value>
                                <horiz>100</horiz>
                                <vert>100</vert>
                            </value>
                        </keyframe>
                        <keyframe>
                            <when>frame4</when>
                            <value>
                                <horiz>150</horiz>
                                <vert>150</vert>
                            </value>
                        </keyframe>
                    </tag8>
                </tag7>
            </generatoritem>
    </tag2>
</tag1>
```

eliminating the excess of nodes, we're trying to obtain the following output format:

```
id='name1'
    instance='frame1'
        horiz='100'
        vert='100'
    instance='frame2'
        horiz='150'
        vert='150'

id='name2'
    instance='frame3'
        horiz='200'
        vert='200'
    instance='frame4'
        horiz='250'
        vert='250'
```

So, based on multiple id values, we work on specific nodes. Tags has to be eliminated and just the critical information retained.

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                                    xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common">
    <!-- disable xml output -->
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:variable name="toprocess">
    <data>
        <node>name1</node>
        <node>name3</node> <!-- and other nodes you want to process -->
    </data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//generatoritem[ @id = exslt:node-set($toprocess)/data/node]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="generatoritem">
    id=<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//keyframe"/>
    <!-- just for the new line -->
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="keyframe">
         instance='<xsl:value-of select="when"/>'
                 horiz='<xsl:value-of select="value/horiz"/>'
                 vert='<xsl:value-of select="value/vert"/>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

should give you as output

xsltproc data.xsl data.xml

```
id='name1'
   instance='frame1'
       horiz='100'
       vert='100'
   instance='frame2'
       horiz='150'
       vert='150'
```

Comment: the solution works great! on multiple <generatoritem id="VALUE"> tags, can you change the code so we actually input the VALUE which has to be retained. in the above example we indicate id='name1' & 'name2'. thanks!

Comment: On the initial generatoritem select, you could modify the select to indicate which nodes you want to match, e.g. <xsl:apply-templates select='.//generatoritem[ @id='name1' ]'/> -- which would match the generatoritem node with an id attribute with a value of 'name1' - is that what you mean?

Comment: :) sure. thanks again! on multiple values, the syntax i am inputting is incorrect. please correct me where i am wrong: generatoritem[ @id="'name1" | "'name2" ]

Comment: generatoritem[ @id='name1' | @id='name2' ] - or you possibly could define a list of node names you want to process somewhere, and use that to process against.

Comment: i like better you second suggestion. how would i do that?

Comment: See above - I've added the node-set extension - your xslt processor will need to support that.

Comment: The thing to note - the select on the generatoritem is set operation - you will get all nodes that match :)

Comment: see http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html for more info on xslt extensions